# Set a Jenkins variable after reading console log line / value --OR-- using the variables used by scripts / commands what Jenkins calls

Tags: jenkins, set, environment-variables, jobs

I DONT need the following:

1. How to set a Jenkins env variable or
2. How to use a environment variables in Jenkins / windows shell / ant / etc scripts.

What I need is opposite of that.

Summary:
1. I have a Jenkins job: ABC_Build
2. This job calls a .bat file (which calls an ANT code / target for packaging / building a 
   build). As we are creating a build, this job know what's the new build label name and 
   ANT is storing it in a variable called "new.build.label". File used is build.xml.

(A NOTE to novice users: If you want to call many Windows commands (.bat / .cmd or 
    commands which creates a windows shell) then, you should call it using "call
    script.bat -Dparam1 -Dparam2...." way).

1. Now, this job calls an another .bat file (which calls an ANT code /target) and uses one 
   of the parameter value which gets generated by first .bat file / ANT package target 
   call (i.e. "new.build.label"). As this is a separate .bat command call to call a new 
   session of ANT code/target, I need to pass the value of "new.build.label" during the 
   call of this step. File used here is deploy.xml.
2. Basically, I'm trying to see how can I set a variable in Jenkins, either by using:
   a. reading the console output of my Jenkins job as I'm echoing the value of 
     new build label in the standard output / console output.
   b. any other way, where I can set a jenkins variable using "new.build.label" ANT 
     variable (once first .bat / ANT package target is finished) and I'm ready to call 
     the 2nd .bat / .cmd / ANT call for doing deployment. Unfortunately, I can't do both 
     package / deploy at the same time.

   I'm also not interested in knowing WHY CAN'T I call target deploy from first ANT 
     session when I already know the value of "new.build.label" as my main request is:

   HOW TO set a jenkins variable using a "variable" which was used by one of the scripts (ANT/Jelly/Groovy/Maven/etc) that Jenkins called.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass environment variables among Jenkins build steps via [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin). In your particular case the following is probably the best way:

1. The first ANT should echo *new.build.label* into a properties file that can be read by *EnvInject* plugin, e.g.:

   ```
   <echo message="new.build.label=${new.build.label}" file="envars.props" />
   ```
2. Create an *Inject environment variables* build step and set "Properties File Path" to `envars.props` (make sure you are dealing with paths correctly). Then *new.build.label* will be available as an environment variable to the rest of your build steps.

By the way, I think it is not a good practice to call ANT from batch files in Jenkins. Use ANT build step instead.

Comment: Thanks. Lets say, Jenkins job is creating the build successfully and storing the build generated in a variable called: "publish.label" which ANT used it during the build. Now I want to send this value in Jenkins "Edit email notification's" subject line. How can I do that?